# Как поместить изображение в <input type="text">?

Tags: html, css

Как поместить изображение в `<input type="text">`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
```

Comment: background-image -ем себе в инпут запихни изображение, googalien1125

Comment: А как тогда подвинуть placeholder чуть правее?

Comment: padding тебе в помощь, наверное? посмотри учебник какой-нибудь. посмотри в http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: Можно пример Вашего кода?

Comment: <input class="banner_input" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">

.banner_input {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;  
    padding: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
input[type="text"] {
    padding-left: 45px;
    background-image: url("images/icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант
`background: #fff (цвет фона) url("http://icofx.ro/tutorials2/img/top.png") 15px 15px (положение относительно левого верхнего угла) no-repeat;`

```css
.banner_input {
  background: #fff url("http://icofx.ro/tutorials2/img/top.png") 15px 15px no-repeat;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  padding: 16px 45px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="banner_input" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-input{
  display: inline-block;   
   margin: 0 0 0 5px;
   position: relative;
}
.b-input:before{
  content: '\f0aa';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 15px;
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
 }
.banner_input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  background: #fff;  
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;  
  padding: 16px 45px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.banner_input:focus{
  border-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="b-input">
   <input class="banner_input" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
</div>
```